# An entity with different attributes depending on its type?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, entity-attribute-value

Trying to design an ER diagram from a given brief for a university project.

I'm confused how I should handle this problem:

```
The items sold in the Food Truck can be of different types: burritos and
beverages. Every item have an ID, a description and a price. Assume that every
Food Truck has infinite stock of each item (i.e. we do not need to track stock levels
in each Food Truck).
All Burritos come with rice, a type of bean, a filling, and a set of optional
toppings. Burritos are priced by size (Mini, Regular, and Grande). Bean types will
vary. Chipp will start by offering two types: black beans and red beans. Burrito
fillings will vary (depending on the season). There are at least 3 types of Burrito
fillings and there should be a vegetarian option.
A Burrito may optionally have toppings: lettuce, tomato, and mild and hot
salsa. Toppings are free, but Chipp will also offer guacamole as a topping for which
there is an extra charge.
The Food Truck also sells different types of refreshing beverages, both
alcoholic and non-alcoholic. All beverages have a size measured in milliliters (just in
case Chipp takes his Food Truck business over the Channel to mainland Europe).
```

The solution I have got to so far is by making two weak entities, both with a relationship, like this:

[image]

Is this the correct way to handle the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Chen's original notation had no symbols for subtyping. A weak entity set without a weak key produced the same result. Your approach is correct within that framework. However, in the same original notation, weak entity sets were associated with identifying relationships (double-bordered diamond) and total participation was indicated with a double line between the entity set and relationship, rather than the (min,max) style of cardinality indicator. This isn't a recommendation to stick to the original notation, but it may be a good idea to verify your answer against your textbook on these points.

A number of different extension notations have been developed to represent subtyping, and to indicate disjointness, which the original notation couldn't. If any of these are covered in your curriculum, I suggest you use them as they're more expressive.

Note also the extra charge requirement on guacamole, which your diagram doesn't include yet. Finally, you indicated price as a derived attribute of item, but I don't see any other attributes it could be calculated from.